# Possible to flow-annotate a point-free function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, flowtype, pointfree

Given these types:

```
type Bar = number;
type Foo = {
  bar: Bar,
};
```

And this point-free conversion function `fooToBar`:

```
import { prop } from 'ramda';
const fooToBar = prop('bar');
```

Is it possible to annotate `fooToBar`'s signature of `Foo -> Bar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [function type annotation docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/) are pretty detailed. It looks like the following should work for you

```
/* @flow */

type Bar = number;
type Foo = {
  bar: Bar,
};

const prop = y => x => x[y];

const fooToBar : Foo => Bar = prop('bar');
```

[Flow says](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgBCAhgE5gC8YAdgK4C2ARnqQNya4EBicclYAb1RgwjMgC4iZADSoAvu1QBjONQDOGMDlJwc-LJQB8YAB5HTAbSwBdRSvWaovACpwS5STz4Vj7-tt0ACgByMVJggEpFIA)

```
No errors!
```